# Analogue of Reshetikhin-Turaev construction for unoriented TQFTs

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft, modular-tensor-categories

The [Reshetikhin-Turaev construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reshetikhin-Turaev+construction) takes a modular tensor category $\mathcal C$ and produces a 3-2-1 oriented TQFT $Z_{\mathcal C}$ such that $Z_{\mathcal C}(S^1) = \mathcal C$.

Is there an analogous construction for 3-2-1 unoriented TQFTs? What kind of structure occurs on $Z(S^1)$ in this case?

For context, I have an unextended 3-dimensional TQFT of unoriented manifolds which I'd like to extend to the circle. Its restriction to oriented manifolds isn't very interesting, so I'm hoping for additional structure on $Z(S^1)$ to capture the unorientable part.

([Turaev and Turner](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506229) answer the analogous question in dimension 2, defining “extended Frobenius algebras” that are equivalent to unoriented 2D TQFTs.)

Comment: Have you looked at these recent papers? https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02728 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07792

Comment: @AlexTurzillo: Thanks, I will take a look!